# Why are logical equality axioms about variables and not terms?

Tags: first-order-logic, axioms

In my book we have this definition about a term:

> If $\mathcal{L}$ us a language, a term of $\mathcal{L}$ is a nontempty
> finite string t of symbols from $\mathcal{L}$ such that either:
>
> 1. t is a variable
> 2. t is a constant symbol
> 3. t:= $ft_1t_2\ldots t_n$ where f is an n-ary function symbol of $\mathcal{L}$ and each of the $t_i$ is a term of $\mathcal{L}$.

The logical axioms about equality are:

> 1. $x=x$ for each variable x.
> 2. Assume that $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$ are variables, and f is an n-ary function symbol then:
>
> $[(x_1=y_1)\land(x_2=y_2)\ldots(x_n=y_n)]\rightarrow
>  (f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=f(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n))$
>
> 3. Assume that $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$ are variables, and R is an n-ary relation symbol then:
>
> $[(x_1=y_1)\land(x_2=y_2)\ldots(x_n=y_n)]\rightarrow
> (R(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\rightarrow R(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n))$

Why are the equality axioms only about variables($x_i,y_i$), and not about terms? Couldn't we for example have $t=t$ for each term?

**Update:**

The book I am reading is "A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic. it can be downloaded from free here: https://knightscholar.geneseo.edu/geneseo-authors/6/ The equality axioms are on page 48-49.

Comment: These "axioms about variables" are sufficient, simply because they imply the corresponding ones "about [any] terms", thanks to the substitution rule.

Comment: @AnneBauval Which substitution rule do you mean? Can you please show me how to do this?

Comment: For instance, apply $(\forall xP(x))\to P(t)$ (where $t$ is a term) to $P(x):=(x=x).$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, But how do we know that $\forall x P(x)$ is true? $\forall x P(x)$ is true if for each $a \in A$ $P(a)$ is true, where $A$ is the universe in the $\mathcal{L}$-structure?(page 29), do we have this?

Comment: Sorry I mean $P(x)[s(x|a)]$ is true for every $a \in A$ and every assignment-function s.

Comment: Or maybe this from chapter 1 shouldn't be used in chapter 2 about deductions?

Comment: For $P(x):=(x=x),$ we have $\forall x P(x)$ is true because it is one of our "axioms about variables" for equality.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, but is this from the book I provided the link to or from other sources? I can not see how I get this from the book I linked to.

Comment: It is from your own post: "1. $x=x$ for each variable x."

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, but how do we go from $P(x)$ for every x, to $\forall x P(x)$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you, but do you see how to do it with the rules in the book I linked to? Can I do it with the rules on page 53?

Comment: Yes, definition 2.4.6 p.53, 1st rule, with  $\psi:=TRUE$ (or any obviously true sentence).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much! Then I only have left that $True \rightarrow P(x)$ is equivalent to $P(x)$, I know that this holds semantically using propositional logic, but how do I show that it holds syntactically using deductions? Is it possible to do this from my book?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens modus ponens p.45

Comment: @AnneBauval I just have two more questions: Can we say that $[True\rightarrow P(x)]\leftrightarrow P(x)$ is a tautology and therefore by page 53 we can deduce it? And from page 53 we also have modus ponenes?(this is a separate question, can we deduce modus ponens by propositional consequence on page 50-53?), and therefore we have that they are equivalent?

Comment: Yes and yes.___

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you

Comment: The general case can be easily proved: (E1) $x=x$; using Lemma 2.7.2 page 62 we get: $\forall x (x=x)$; using (Q1) in the form: $\forall x (x=x) \to (t=t)$ we get the result by Modus Ponens.

Answer (score 0):

At least for pedagogical reasons, in my opinion the equality axioms should indeed talk about arbitrary terms rather than just variables. For instance, from the given rules alone there's no way to conclude $$f(f(u))=f(f(u))$$ if $f$ is a unary function symbol and $u$ is a variable.

However, additional inference rules may come to the rescue here. For instance, **universal generalization** will give us $\forall x,y(x=y\rightarrow f(x)=f(y))$, and then **universal instantiation** (setting $x=y=f(u)$) gives us $$f(u)=f(u)\rightarrow f(f(u))=f(f(u)),$$ which in turn will give us $f(f(u))=f(f(u))$.

But just because something is mathematically acceptable doesn't mean it's a good idea. Having the equality axioms be so "fragile" in my opinion makes them, and the whole logical apparatus being introduced, harder to think about.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am reading the book " A friendly introduction to mathematical logic": It can be downloaded for free here: https://knightscholar.geneseo.edu/geneseo-authors/6/  . The equality axioms are on page 48-49. Do you see any way to get equality for terms by the Rules Of Inteference in the book?, the rules of inference are on page 50.

Comment: @user394334 I don't immediately, but I wouldn't be surprised if I were missing something. My suspicion is that the book is *probably* correct, but that regardless of whether it is in fact mathematically correct it's not a good pedagogical choice.